# Add an argument to a function's default arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, default-arguments

I'm wondering if there's a way to add an argument to the default arguments a function takes.

For instance:

```
SOME_CITIES = ["Gotham","Chicago"]
def do_something(name, cities=SOME_CITIES):
    for city in cities:
        print(name, city)

do_something("Clark")
>> Clark Gotham
>> Clark Chicago

# Can I do something like this (pseudocode, obviously):
do_something("Clark", *["New York", "LA"])
>> Clark Gotham
>> Clark Chicago
>> Clark New York
>> Clark LA
```

The idea is `do_something("Clark", *"New York")` would run through the function, doing `Gotham`, `Chicago`, and *then* the city I added, `New York`.

This is similar from my understanding of `**kwargs`, but that would look like:

```
def do_something(name, **kwargs):
    # Code here...

do_something("Clark", SOME_CITIES, "New York")
```

But that requires me to recall to send `SOME_CITIES` through, when I'd like to include that by default.  Does that make sense?

Edit: The `SOME_CITIES` may not always be a list. It could be two functions, i.e. `SOME_FUNCTIONS = func1, func2`.  Also - as some answers seem to get at below, if this is a bad idea and `kwargs`/`args` is better, that's fine too just let me know and explain a little :)

Comment: You could add the default values inside the function, something like: `for city in SOME_CITIES + cities` and let `cities` be empty by default?

Comment: Be careful with using a mutable object for the default argument, see ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](//stackoverflow.com/q/1132941).

Answer (score 2):

Python has no syntax or behaviour to extend lists used as a default argument, no. You can simply use the `*args` catch-all parameter here and concatenate *in the function*:

```
SOME_CITIES = ("Gotham", "Chicago")
def do_something(name, cities=SOME_CITIES, *further_cities):
    for city in cities + further_cities:
        print(name, city)
```

If the sequences are expected to be large, you could use `itertools.chain()` instead of concatenation. Note the change to using tuples here, which avoids a common pitfall of using a mutable data type where you never intent to make changes to the value at runtime anyway.

You need to be extremely careful when using a list as a default argument value, see ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument). In *this specific case* there is little point in avoiding it as `SOME_CITIES` is also defined outside of the function and you have more options to alter that object, but you may want to consider using a `None` sentinel instead:

```
SOME_CITIES = ["Gotham", "Chicago"]
def do_something(name, cities=None, *further_cities):
    if cities is None:
        # start with a base list
        cities = SOME_CITIES
    cities = cities + list(further_cities)
    for city in cities:
        print(name, city)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your default parameter in your function to `*args`, and then use `functools.partial`:

```
import functools
SOME_CITIES = ["Gotham","Chicago"]
OTHER_CITIES = ["New York", "LA"]
def do_something(name, *cities):
  for city in cities:
     print(name, city)

new_funct = functools.partial(do_something, 'clark', *SOME_CITIES)
new_funct(*OTHER_CITIES)
```

Output:

```
clark Gotham
clark Chicago
clark New York
clark LA
```